# merge x and x + n lines

Tags: shell-script, shell, paste, line

I am writing a script which returns 15 lines of titles and 15 lines of URLs.

```
title 1
title 2
title 3
*snip*
title 14
title 15
http://example.com/query?1
http://example.com/query?2
http://example.com/query?3
*snip*
http://example.com/query?14
http://example.com/query?15
```

I'd like to merge it in such a way that produces the following output:

```
title 1 http://example.com/query?1
title 2 http://example.com/query?2
title 3 http://example.com/query?3
*snip*
title 15 http://example.com/query?15
```

Upon light inspection and the guidance of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605450), I found the command `paste`. However, `paste` does not allow for the performance of more complex behaviors like the ones described above. Is there another tool or combination of tools I can use in order to accomplish the aforementioned behavior?

Do note that I'm looking to use all standard coreutils behavior, if at all possible.

Comment: You could use `sed -n -e '1,15p' and `sed -n -e 16,30p` to split your file prior to using `paste`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `pr` command

```bsh
pr -2t -s" " file
```